# How to kill a process redirected to /dev/null

Tags: perl

I am trying to initiate the execution of monitor.pl by using this following pipe mechanism:

```
$cpid = open($fh, '-|', "./monitor.pl >/dev/null") or die "can not open pipe\n";
```

The output of monitor.pl is redirected to /dev/null.

The problem which I am facing is that I am not able to kill the processes even after using the following code:

```
kill ('INT', $cpid) if defined $cpid;
close $fh if defined $fh;
```

So please can anyone suggest me how to kill the process monitor.pl >/dev/null.

Comment: `/dev/null` isn't a process!

Comment: No one said you are, dear @devnull.

Comment: What is `monitor.pl`? Maybe it features a signal handler?

Comment: @devnull Oh the irony of the fact that you stumbled on this question.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/null is not a process it is a special file.

but
to kill following command. 
monitor.pl >/dev/null

type

```
ps -aef | grep monitor.pl
kill -9 PID of the process
```

These are the commands you can easily adjust themm in perl code.